# Add condition for not plotting in some cases

Tags: plotting, functions, conditional

I have the following function. Now I want to add condition  to not plot when the function is 
`ComplexInfinity`, `Indeterminate`, or `always negative for all value of d`. 
So the code shouldn't plot cases with `{a, b} = {1,2}`, `{a, b} = {1,1}`, `{a, b} = {1,3}`.
How can I add the condition?
I know you may come up with some simple method with a different code but I'd like to use this structure so I can apply it to my other problem by MassDefect's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236196/how-to-plot-a-very-large-table-of-plots-faster/236222?noredirect=1#comment596611_236222).

```
f[a_, b_, d_] := (a + b)/(a - b) d;
tup1 = Tuples@{{1, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 3}}
Quiet@Plot[{f[##, d], 1}, {d, 0, 1}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["a= `` b= ``", ##]]] & @@@ 
 tup1[[1 ;; 4]]
```

EDIT: the function shouldn't plot if it's smaller than or equal to 0 for all value in (0,1)

Comment: for `Quiet@(f[##, 0] & @@@ tup1)` you have `{0, Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0, 0, Indeterminate, 0}`, so it is effectively never "always negative" if d ==0. Am I missing something?

Comment: and `Quiet@(f[##, 1] & @@@ tup1)` returns `{-3, ComplexInfinity, 1, -2, -1, -1, Indeterminate, -1}`. Does it mean that you expect just one plot to be shown from sample tuple?

Comment: `d` is a range not a specific value

Comment: I understand that and that is the essence of my question - your range will never return "always negative" but you ask to rule it out. So we have different results in different points. Can you say exactly what the tuple in your example should return?

Comment: I think I made too strict condition. The function shouldn't plot if it's smaller than or equal to zero for the whole range of d. Is that clear?

Comment: In the code above, the code should plot only the case `{a, b} = {1,0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `NumberQ` rules out `ComplexInfinity` and `NumericQ` rules out `Indeterminate`.

---

```
Clear[twoStepCheckAndPlot1];
twoStepCheckAndPlot1[tup_] := 
 Block[{condition1 = {NumberQ, NumericQ}, condition2 = NonNegative, 
   tup$n, tup$d, d, check},
  
  (* make function that rules out errors *)
  check = AllTrue[Through[condition1[#]], TrueQ] &;

  (* save in temporary variable tup$n only those pair from tuple that raise no errors*)
  tup$n = Pick[tup, Boole@Quiet@(check /@ (f[##, 0] & @@@ tup)), 1];

  (* save in temporary variable tup$d only those pairs from tup$n that makes f => 0 *)
  tup$d = 
   Pick[tup$n,Boole@Resolve[ForAll[d, 0 <= d <= 1, condition2@f[##, d]], 
        Reals] & @@@ tup$n, 1];
  
  (* plot only pairs that saved in tup$d and satisfy all conditions *)
  Plot[{f[##, d], 1}, {d, 0, 1}, 
     PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["a= `` b= ``", ##]]] & @@@ tup$d
]
```

---

**Update** with another example and a bit alternative procedure.

```
g[a_, b_, d_] := 1/(a + b + d);
tup1 = Tuples@{{1, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 3}}
```

The code should rule out `{0, 0}` because it is `ComplexInfinity` while `d == 0`.

```
Clear[twoStepCheckAndPlot];
twoStepCheckAndPlot[tup_] := 
 Block[{condition2 = NonNegative, tup$d, d, someN = -100},
  
  h[a_, b_, d_] := 
   Quiet @ g[a, b, d] /. {ComplexInfinity -> someN, Indeterminate -> someN};
  
  tup$d = 
   Pick[tup, 
    Boole@Resolve[ForAll[d, 0 <= d <= 1, condition2 @ h[##, d]], 
        Reals] & @@@ tup, 1];
  
  Plot[{h[##, d], 1}, {d, 0, 1}, 
     PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["a= `` b= ``", ##]]] & @@@ tup$d]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117804/discussion-on-answer-by-garej-add-condition-for-not-plotting-in-some-cases).

Comment: just a side question: why did you name variables like `tup$d,  tup$n`? Couldn't find any information about this.

Comment: @anhnha, no special purpose, no meaning in MMA, these are just my way of var naming. I'd used something like `tup_n` or `tup_d` elsewhere, but MMA precludes that. This is just to remind yourself, that those variables originated from `tup` and `n` is for 'numeric', `d` that it is connected with `d` parameter in the function.

Comment: Would it be OK to use something like `tup$1, tup$2`?  Does it differ from `$tup1, $tup2`?

Comment: @anhnha, you can do both, but first option is not recommended and second is against the convention. You may take a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25183/what-is-sign-in-mathematica). `$` in the beginning is a *convention* for constants. You'd better avoid this sign altogether :))

Answer (score 1):

Try e.g.:

```
f[a_, b_, d_] := (a + b)/(a - b) d; tup1 = 
 Tuples@{{1, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 3}}; 
Quiet@Check[
    t = Plot[{f[##, d], 1}, {d, 0, 1}, 
      PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["a= `` b= ``", ##]]]; t, 
    Nothing[]] & @@@ tup1[[1 ;; 4]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more?
Also it still plots the function when it's negative for all d like cases `{a, b} = {1,2}, {a, b} = {1,3}`

Comment: `Check` will check if there are any messages generated. If not, it returns the plot, if yes, it returns `Nothing[]`

Comment: I want to add some more  general conditions so that doesn't really solve all cases